# Extracting data from a custom struct array

Tags: c++, struct

I am trying to make a cluster of particles and assign each particle an x, y, and z co-ordinate picked from a random normal distribution. 
I wanted to see what positions I was getting and decided to display my x co-ordinates. This is essentially what I am doing:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <random>

using namespace std; 
struct PARTICLE { 
public:   
double x;   
double y; 
double z;
PARTICLE() {   } };

int main() {

//set up cluster of particles   
int numberOfParticles = 10;   
std::random_device rd{};   
std::mt19937 gen{rd()};   
std::normal_distribution<> d{0,1};

PARTICLE *clusterOfParticles [numberOfParticles];

for (int ind=0; ind<numberOfParticles; ind++){
    cout<<"test"<<endl;
    clusterOfParticles[ind]->x = d(gen);
    cout<<clusterOfParticles[ind]->x<<endl; }

return 0; 
}
```

I am not getting any error message, and I can see "test" being displayed. But I am not seeing my x coordinates. Are they even being stored in memory? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You have not initialized any of the pointers in `clusterOfParticles` prior to using them.  This is undefined behavior.  If you want to use pointers, they need to point to valid memory.

Comment: Or don't use pointers at all, and just have an array of objects.

Comment: Also note that the array you're having is technically a [*variable-length array*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), and those are not part of standard C++. If you make the variable `const` (or better yet `constexpr`) then it's okay.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, thank you! that worked!

Comment: @paddy to initialize clusterOfParticles, would I need to plug in 10 (x,y,z) triplets?

Comment: If you want to use more standard C/C++ you can use alloca (see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html, its still not standard though...) instead of  variable length arrays. 
But do consider using std::vector<PARTICLE> instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments below your question basically give already the answer. Your array of pointers point to nowhere.

And you are using a C99 Style Variable Length Array (VLA). That is not allowed in C++.

I do not want to, but I anyway show you the solution with pointers. Use:

```
PARTICLE *clusterOfParticles = new PARTICLE [numberOfParticles];

// Your code

delete [] clusterOfParticles;
```

But I do not want to do that. Instead I say:

Do never ever use C-Style arrays in the future. There is no need for it.

Do not use pointers. Never use raw pointer. Forget the above example. At least use std::unique_ptr.

Modify your code to

```
// We will use a vector
std::vector<PARTICLE> clusterOfParticles(numberOfParticles);

for (int ind=0; ind<numberOfParticles; ind++){
    cout<<"test"<<endl;
    clusterOfParticles[ind].x = d(gen);
    cout<<clusterOfParticles[ind].x<<endl; }
```

Much simpler and less error prone.